# Why does declaration of the same name inside the same declarative region is denied?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int a=5;
char a='a';

int main(){ std::cout << a;}
```

It is because:

```
test.cpp:5:6: error: conflicting declaration ‘char a’
test.cpp:4:5: error: ‘a’ has a previous declaration as ‘int a’
```

But where does this restriction specified in the standard? I can't find it. Please give me a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR). See n3797 S3.2/1.

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.

There really is no more to be said. Each of those lines is a *definition* of `a` (not a *declaration*). The program is ill-formed.

If these declarations were in different translation units the program would still be ill-formed, but the applicable rule is different. See S3.5/10.

Comment: I agree. But ODR doesn't work for declaration-not-definition. You can see my answer to explain the behavior in that case.

Comment: They *are* declarations. Declarations introduce names. Ex. [basic]/5 "Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a declaration. Every name that denotes a label is
introduced either by a `goto` statement or a *labeled-statement*." You can also prove this grammatically and via [basic.def]/2. For the ODR to apply, you had to prove that those two names refer to the same variable, and I don't think this is the case. As far as I can tell, they refer to different entities with the same name, see [basic]/3-4

Answer (score 7):

C++11 §3.3.1 ¶4

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; or
> - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name
>     and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable or enumerator, or all refer to functions
>     and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden (3.3.10). [ Note: A
>     namespace name or a class template name must be unique in its declarative region (7.3.2, Clause 14).
>     — end note ]

Neither of these conditions is met in your case, so your program is ill-formed.

Comment: It is because odr violated in that case.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I don't think so. The ODR is 3.2. Those names refer to different entities but have the same name. The ODR is about the number of definitions for *one* entity.

Comment: Exactly; ODR talks about multiple *definitions* of the same object, while here we are talking about multiple *declarations* in the same declarative region.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong, as it refers to _declarations_ where the code contains _definitions_. This is an ODR situation, see my answer.

Comment: @david.pfx definitions are also declarations; perhaps this code violates both sections

Comment: It is unclear that two declarations with different type shall be denote the different entity.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The standard is explicit and categorical in its treatment of declarations and the ODR rule in S3.2. I read S3.3 as slightly relaxing the rules if certain conditions are met, not as an alternative way of arriving at the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason in the current case is ODR as rightly observed by *david.pfx*.
But consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;
extern char a;

int main(){ std::cout << a;}
```

The actual reason is not the violation of 3.3. Actually in the 13/1 said:

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single
>   name in the same scope, that name is said to be overloaded. By
>   extension, two declarations in the same scope that declare **the same
>   name but with different types** are called overloaded declarations. Only
>   function and function template declarations can be overloaded;
>   variable and type declarations cannot be overloaded.

Hence, I'm just trying to overload non-function declaration.

Comment: For this (different) question I agree that ODR does not apply. This is still a violation of linkage S3.5/10 as per the note to my answer. However I read S13/1 as saying that overloading does not apply. This is a conflict of declarations, not a failed overload. In practice, I doubt it matters.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be applied as an edit to the original question.

Comment: @david.pfx I don't understand why it is not an answer. I give a quote which denies an overloading everyone except functions. `extern int a; extern char a;` is overloading by definition (Sec. 13/1)

Comment: It's not an answer because it doesn't answer the original question. It asks a new question with a new code sample, and tries to answer that. Either ask a new question, or edit the original question. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @david.pfx It is a different code sample, but the answer might be the same. Both are illegal and it's possible that both are illegal for the same reason. In fact, I think it's probable that any rule that makes *this* program illegal also makes the program in this question illegal.

Comment: @dyp: Sure thing. Which is exactly why it could be an edit of the original question. It's still not an answer.