# Why does declaration of the variable with different types denote the different entity

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;
extern char a;

int main(){ std::cout << a;}
```

As I understand, it is because there are two declarations of `a` in the same declarative region denote the different entities. It seems obvious.

**But where does the standard say that those two entities are different?** I've read 3.1-3.4 sections but can't find anything.

Can you find a quote which explicitly or implicitly disallows this?

Comment: This isn't clear; the compilation error is nothing to do with types, it's simply that you've redefined the symbol `a`.  You'd get the same problem with `int a = 5; int a = 7;`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm sorry for this typo. I've updated my question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I mean that we're consider redeclaration-not-definition of a. Of course, ODR may be applied...

Comment: It's still not clear what this has to do with types.  `extern int a = 5; extern int a = 7;` won't compile either.

Comment: @haccks It is not duplicate because there is a different questions.

Comment: How many times will you ask the same question? Doesn't the quoted standard justify your question in the previous question?

Comment: @haccks At once it is not the same questions. If you think the opposite then give me a quote from the previous answer which is answering to the current question.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: I guess everyone here agrees that the question is the same and the answer applies. I do not understand where you see the difference. Please explain.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Which part of the quoted standart does **NOT** answer your question?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You say it *in your question*: "there are two declarations of `a` (i.e. two declarations using the same unqualified-id `a`) in the same declarative region denoting different entities". From answer to your previous question: "Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name, they shall all refer to the same entity"

Comment: @dyp But I asked why does declarations with the different type denote the different entity?

Comment: @dyp I found answer to my question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973281/why-does-declaration-of-the-same-name-inside-the-same-declarative-region-is-deni/23976676#23976676

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I'm sorry, I lost sight of the title. Reopening..

Answer (score 1):

3.5/10:

> After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical

So you either have two declarations of the same variable (a variable is an entity) with non-identical types, or two different variables with the same name. Either way it's an error.

Comment: Ah, great, that's the missing piece in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

[basic]/3

> An *entity* is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type,
>   class member, template, template specialization, namespace, parameter
>   pack, or `this`.

/6

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes the reference or object.

The two declarations `extern int a;` and `extern char a;` each declare a variable. The name `a` in the first case refers to an entity which is an object of type `int`, and in the second case it refers to an entity which is an object of type `char`.

An object has a type [intro.object]/1. The objects denoted by the two `a` have different types, hence they're not the same objects (literally).

There's still the question of type-punning, but I think that produces only an expression with a type different from the object it refers to. I don't think it's possible (= allowed) to produce an object which has two types, I interpret that "An object has a type" in [intro.object]/1 as "an object has exactly one type".

I think it's safe to conclude from here that two objects with different types are different objects and hence different *entities*.

Comment: Very interesting info about objects. I skipped the first clause in the standard. It was for nothing.

Comment: But I don't understand why we cannot reasoning that it is invalid language construction as "Only function and function template declarations can be overloaded"?

Comment: I do agree 13/1 also forbids this (i.e. I disagree with david.pfx), however I would think that there's (also) an answer in one of the previous sections about declarations, scope and name lookup.